# calculate the sum of all the digits of number till you get a single digit in java script r give idea to improve below program

Tags: javascript

```
while(no>0) {
 sum=sum+no%10;
 no=Math.floor(no/10);
 }
 alert("Sum of digits "+sum);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *"r give idea to improve below program"* is not a question. If it *were*, it would be off-topic for SO. A much, much better version of this might be on-topic at http://codereview.stackexchange.com. But it would have to be much better.

Comment: So u are gonna pay something for the answer?

Comment: You need to actually ask a question. All I see is a title and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript Function

```
function DigitSum(var num)
{
 var sum = 0;

 while (num > 0)
{
   sum += parseInt(num % 10);

   num = parseInt(num/10);
}
if (sum > 9)
{
   sum = DigitSum(sum);
}
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Yes it should sum until its a single digit

Comment: Via Recursion , See the function DigitSum called inside DigitSum

Comment: If you are new to Programming its not the place here Dude!!!! Kindly learn some stuff before you ask these questions :)

Answer (score -1):

This should get you what you want.

```
function get_sum_of_digits(num) {
    num_str = num.toString();
    sum = 0;
    for(var i =0;i<num_str.length;i++) {
       sum += parseInt(num_str[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}

var res = get_sum_of_digits(198);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Of course you can. Why don't you open the javascript console and just copy/paste my code. It will return 18 (1+9+8)

Comment: The output should be 9 . It will sum unless it is a single digit.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part of the requirement. The OP wasn't being too clear I guess. Thanks!